# yield waitforseconds() not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, yield, unityscript

I have the following code in a player object:

```
function Start () 
{
    GUI = GameObject.FindWithTag("GUI").GetComponent(InGameGUI);
}

function OnCollisionEnter(hitInfo : Collision)
{
    if(hitInfo.relativeVelocity.magnitude >= 2) //if we hit it too hard, explode!
    { 
        Explode();
    }
}

function Explode() //Drop in a random explosion effect, and destroy ship
{
    var randomNumber : int = Random.Range(0,shipExplosions.length);
    Instantiate(shipExplosions[randomNumber], transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Destroy(gameObject);

    GUI.Lose();
}
```

And my GUI.Lose() function looks like this:

```
function Lose()
{
    print("before yield");
    yield WaitForSeconds(3);
    print("after yield");
    Time.timeScale = 0;
    guiMode = "Lose";
}
```

When the explode function is called, the loose function is called and I see the message "before yield" print out.  I wait three seconds, but I never see the "after yield" message.

If I take the yield out, the function works as I would expect minus the waiting for 3 seconds.

This is on Unity 4.  This code is directly from a tutorial that I believe was created on Unity 3.5.  I assume the code worked in Unity 3.5 because there are no comments on the sites asking why the yield isn't working.

What stupid thing am I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [StartCoroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html), like so:

```
function Explode() //Drop in a random explosion effect, and destroy ship
{
    var randomNumber : int = Random.Range(0,shipExplosions.length);
    Instantiate(shipExplosions[randomNumber], transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Destroy(gameObject);

    // Change here.
    yield StartCoroutine(GUI.Lose());

    // Or use w/out a 'yield' to return immediately.
    //StartCoroutine(GUI.Lose());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this got me close enough to finish it up.  I placed the yield StartCoroutine(GUI.Lose()) before the Destroy.  Before that, I set renderer.enabled = false; so my game object would hide.  The Lose() function completes and then my gameObject is destroyed.

Comment: Explanation: because the execution of a coroutine can be paused at any point using the yield statement.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using a simple Invoke on your Lose function.

```
function Start () 
{
    GUI = GameObject.FindWithTag("GUI").GetComponent(InGameGUI);
}

function OnCollisionEnter(hitInfo : Collision)
{
    if(hitInfo.relativeVelocity.magnitude >= 2) //if we hit it too hard, explode!
    { 
        Explode();
    }
}

function Explode() //Drop in a random explosion effect, and destroy ship
{
    var randomNumber : int = Random.Range(0,shipExplosions.length);
    Instantiate(shipExplosions[randomNumber], transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Destroy(gameObject);
    Invoke("YouLose", 3.0f);
}

function YouLose()
{
    GUI.Lose();
}
```